# java Expression too complex reduce the number of conditionl operators

Tags: java, conditional-operator

We have a program that we run against our code to adhere to some coding standards.

The program says:

> Expression should not be too complex, reduce the number of conditional operators used int he expression Min allowed 3.

How can I reduce the number of conditional operators?  perhaps put the keyevents in an array?

```
public boolean onlyNumbers(KeyEvent evt) {
    char c = evt.getKeyChar();
    boolean returnValue = true;
    if (
        !(
            Character.isDigit(c) 
            || c == KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE
            || c == KeyEvent.VK_DELETE 
            || c == KeyEvent.VK_END 
            || c == KeyEvent.VK_HOME
        )
        || c == KeyEvent.VK_PAGE_UP
        || c == KeyEvent.VK_PAGE_DOWN
        || c == KeyEvent.VK_INSERT
    ) {
        evt.consume();
        returnValue = false;
    }
    return returnValue;
}
```

Comment: Is this parenthesized correctly?  The tests for `VK_BACK_SPACE`, `VK_DELETE`, `VK_END`, and `VK_HOME` are in an expression that has a `!` on it; but `VK_PAGE_UP`, `VK_PAGE_DOWN`, and `VK_INSERT` are outside.  That makes me think some of the comparisons are redundant just according to Boolean algebra.  But first I'd need to know whether you're sure the expression is correct.

Comment: I formatted your code a little so it would be easier to see structure of your conditions. Please correct it in case if it is not structure you wanted to create.

Comment: Indeed - you could remove the last three tests (PgUp, PgDn, Insert) altogether as they're covered by the negative tests - if the key is any of those three then it's also not a digit, backspace, delete, end or home

Comment: good eye.  I don't see a reason why the 3 were outside.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
final String junkChars = new String(new char[] {
    KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE,
    KeyEvent.VK_DELETE,
    KeyEvent.VK_END,
    KeyEvent.VK_HOME
    /* The last three seem unused in the latest version
    KeyEvent.VK_PAGE_UP,
    KeyEvent.VK_PAGE_DOWN,
    KeyEvent.VK_INSERT */
});
if(!Character.isDigit(c) && junkChars.indexOf(c) == -1) {
   evt.consume();
   return false;
}  else {
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I liked this one the best.

Answer (score 2):

A strict refactor of your sample would look like:

```
public boolean onlyNumbers(KeyEvent evt) {
    char c = evt.getKeyChar();
    boolean returnValue = true;
    boolean bad = Character.isDigit(c);
    bad |= (c == KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE);
    bad |= (c == KeyEvent.VK_DELETE);
    bad |= (c == KeyEvent.VK_END);
    bad |= (c == KeyEvent.VK_HOME);
    boolean good = (c == KeyEvent.VK_PAGE_UP);
    good |= c == KeyEvent.VK_PAGE_DOWN;
    good |= c == KeyEvent.VK_INSERT;
    if (!bad || good) {
        evt.consume();
        returnValue = false;
    }
    return returnValue;
}
```

This highlights the concerns others have noted about the placing of your brackets

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do this is to construct a `HashSet<Character> keys` containing all the characters you want to test for, and then use `keys.contains(c)` to test whether it's one of them.

Alternatively, you could use a `switch` statement, and let all those characters fall through to the same block of code.

But my personal favourite would be to ignore the warning. The code is perfectly clear as it is (modulo ajb's comment about parentheses).

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it. Could be improved by using an array.

```
public boolean onlyNumbers(KeyEvent evt) {
    char c = evt.getKeyChar();
    boolean returnValue;

    returnValue =  !(Character.isDigit(c));
    returnValue &= !(c == KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE);
    returnValue &= !(c == KeyEvent.VK_DELETE);
    returnValue &= !(c == KeyEvent.VK_END);
    returnValue &= !(c == KeyEvent.VK_HOME);
    returnValue |= (c == KeyEvent.VK_PAGE_UP);
    returnValue |= (c == KeyEvent.VK_PAGE_DOWN);
    returnValue |= (c == KeyEvent.VK_INSERT);
    if(returnValue)
    {
        evt.consume();
        returnValue = !returnValue;
    }
    return returnValue;
}
```

The first five and last three assignments could be compacted in their respective groupings to two total assignments, but that will boil down to your coding standards.

Comment: I like this one the best.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: No problem. Glad to be of assistance.

Comment: You can't like two answers the best! :P. (Doesn't matter to me as long as you got your answer.)